# parse-server source build error when run 'npm install'

Tags: build, npm, parse-server, babeljs

I tried download parse-server source([2.2.21 on github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/tree/2.2.21)) and build but I getting this error.

run command 
`$ npm install`

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

> bcrypt@0.8.7 install /Users/dora/parse-server/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bcrypt_lib.node
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
```

...

```
> parse-server@2.2.20 prepublish /Users/dora/parse-server
> npm run build
> parse-server@2.2.20 build /Users/dora/parse-server
```

occurred error

```
> babel src/ -d lib/

src/AccountLockout.js -> lib/AccountLockout.js
src/Adapters/AdapterLoader.js -> lib/Adapters/AdapterLoader.js
src/Adapters/Analytics/AnalyticsAdapter.js -> lib/Adapters/Analytics/AnalyticsAdapter.js
src/Adapters/Cache/CacheAdapter.js -> lib/Adapters/Cache/CacheAdapter.js

...

src/Adapters/Logger/LoggerAdapter.js -> lib/Adapters/Logger/LoggerAdapter.js
SyntaxError: src/Adapters/Logger/WinstonLogger.js: `addTransport` has already been exported. Exported identifiers must be unique. (98:17)
   96 | }
   97 | 
>  98 | export { logger, addTransport, configureLogger, removeTransport };
      |                  ^
   99 | export default logger;
  100 |
```

How to fix this?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the file WinstonLogger.js (./src/Adapters/Logger/WinstonLogger.js)

and remove the "export" words before the functions addTransport, configureLogger and removeTransport it should work.